# Select only one item in two ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have two `ListView`, each bound to a specific collection in my ViewModel and I want to be able to select only one item globally.

Each `ListView` has its `SelectedItem` property bound to the same property in the ViewModel.

My probleme is as follow: when I select an item in a `ListView`, and then select another item in the other ListView, the first item stays selected.
I could achieve this with some code-behind, but I want to know if a pure XAML solution exists.

**XAML:**

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList1}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList2}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Does `MySelectedItem` property raises `INPC.PropertyChanged` event when changed?

Comment: Yes, the PropertyChanged event is fired in the setter of this property.

Comment: and `MySelectedItem` is one property for both `ListView`'s, is defined in the same class as `MyList1` and `MyList2` and you confirmed in debugger that setter is called when you select something in either `ListView`?

Comment: MySelectedItem is declared as an object and the two lists contain different object types. Everything works fine from a viewmodel point of view, the problem is just the selection in the view.

Comment: Do `MyList1` and `MyList2` contain the same instances of items?

Comment: No. As stated above, the two list are from different classes.

Answer (score 7):

I finally got it working, by just replacing `SelectedItem` by `SelectedValue`.

In this use case, both properties have the same behaviour, but the latter one handles correctly the unselection if the bound selected item is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Mode=TwoWay` in your `SelectedItem`. It should work.

Comment: Selecteditem in an itemscontrol binds two way by default. You're basically forcing the default value.