# wpf binding upwards: bind to view model property inside nested uiElement

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF project with a view model and some nested UI elements. Here is the (relevant section of) XAML:

```
<UserControl> // DataContext is MyVM (set programmatically)
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Trees}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Subtrees}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contents}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedContent}" // won't work: Tree has no such property
                              SelectionMode="Single"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

Here the code for the ViewModel class:

```
public class MyVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tree> Trees { get; set; }

    private object _selectedContent;
    public string SelectedContent
    {
        get => _selectedContent;
        set
        {
            _selectedContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the code for class `Tree`:

```
public class Tree
{
    public IEnumerable<Tree> Subtrees { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

I want to allow only one selection globally for all `ListViews`. Just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009661/5333340), I want to bind all `ListViews` to the property `SelectedContent` in the view model `MyVM`.

The problem is that the data context of the `ListView` is a `Tree`, and not the `MyVM` from the top user control. (It should be `Tree`, since we want to show the `Contents`.) I know I can bind downwards using `SelectedValuePath`, but how do I go up instead in order to bind `SelectedValue` to the `MyVM` property `SelectedContent`?

I tried `SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType ={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=SelectedContent}"`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84317/5333340), saying:

> Just wanted to note here that **if you want to bind to a property in the
> DataContext of the RelativeSource then you must explicitly specify it**:
> {Binding Path=DataContext.SomeProperty, RelativeSource=.... This was
> somewhat unexpected for me as a newbie when I was trying to bind to a
> parent's DataContext within a DataTemplate.

This comment deserves more attention, so I'll use it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
  Mode=FindAncestorBindingContext, AncestorType ={x:Type MyVM}}, 
  Path=SelectedContent}"
```

Maybe, you'll need to describe your model's namespace in header:

```
xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:_your_namespace_.ViewModels"
```

and use

```
SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
  Mode=FindAncestorBindingContext, AncestorType ={x:Type viewmodel:MyVM}}, 
  Path=SelectedContent}"
```